# Adding waypoints to DirectionFinder object in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

i use directionFinder in Google Apps Script application and I want do add some waypoints. Everything works well when i add this like this:

```
var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setOrigin(start).setDestination(end)
 .addWaypoint('Berlin')
 .addWaypoint('Hamburg')
 .getDirections();
```

but when I want do add some waypoints dynamicaly in loop like this:

```
 var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setOrigin(start).setDestination(end)

 while (results.hasNext()) {
      directions.addWaypoint('Berlin')
      directions.addWaypoint('Hamm')
     }

 directions.getDirections();
```

finally the object directions hasn't any waypoints. What I'm doing wrong? There isn't possible to add waypoints in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple script (see bellow). It works correctly - the `res` contains 4 legs.

```js
function testMapWayPoints() {
  var directions  = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setOrigin('Berlin').setDestination('Rotterdam');
  var wayPoints = ['Potsdam', 'Hanover', 'Dortmund'];
  for (var i = 0; i < wayPoints.length; i++) {
    directions.addWaypoint(wayPoints[i]);
  }
  var res = directions.getDirections();
}
```

I assume that the `results.hasNext()` returns false. If not then, could you create a minimum compilable example/function which is possible to copy-and-paste to the editor and which reproduces the problem.

**Update 00**: Additionally I wrote a [deployed web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz6rcd3hGXQti69IM1v-mbxS002jNSjy4nTnN0g1nxJ96fpLBxV/exec) demonstrating that the `addWaypoint` function works. [Here](https://script.google.com/d/12yjBH61ai--RyZhj5OEFuRa6IiUkXKLbtK18XsSr-cOMfqgvB7WAFeX2/edit) is the app source code.

Comment: megabyte, looks like the links to the source code don't work anymore